# Numpy 2d array union when guaranteed nonzero equality

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have two NxN numpy arrays, they are equal size.

If a given row and column in the first array is nonzero, then it is guaranteed that we either have the same value in the same row and column of the other array, or that we have a zero there.

If a given row and column in the first array is zero, then we can have either a zero or a nonzero value in that row and column in the other array.

I would like to combine both array, such that for every [row,col], if one array has a value of zero, and the other has nonzero, then my second array will be modified (if necessary), to have the nonzero value.

And, if they both have a nonzero value, (which is guaranteed to be the same value), then there will be no modification for that row,column - it stays the same.

Example:

array 1:

```
[[0,9],[2,0]]
```

array 2:

```
[[0,0],[2,2]]
```

After doing my "union", I want array 2 to be:

```
[[0,9],[2,2]]
```

What is a fast way to do this for large matrices?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you wanna do is to change the zeros in second array to items in same index in first array. You can do the following:

```
mask = arr2 == 0
arr2[mask] = arr1[mask]
```

Demo:

```
In [7]: arr1 = np.array([[0,9],[2,0]])

In [8]: arr2 = np.array([[0,0],[2,2]])

In [9]: mask = arr2 == 0

In [10]: arr2[mask] = arr1[mask]

In [11]: arr2
Out[11]: 
array([[0, 9],
       [2, 2]])
```

Comment: so cool!  I did not think it would be possible to do it so elegantly.

Comment: @TravisBlack That's the magic of vectorization and here of course some abstractions.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking for "fast" you may be interested in `np.copyto`:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 2, (100, 100))
>>> b = np.random.randint(-1, 1, (100, 100))
>>> 
>>> 
>>> timeit("bk = b.copy(); mask=bk==0; bk[mask] = a[mask]", globals=globals(), number=10000)
1.3142543959984323
>>> timeit("bp = b.copy(); np.copyto(bp, a, where=bp==0)", globals=globals(), number=10000)
0.7330851459992118
>>> 
# check results are the same
>>> bk = b.copy(); mask=bk==0; bk[mask] = a[mask]
>>> bp = b.copy(); np.copyto(bp, a, where=bp==0)
>>> np.all(bk==bp)
True
```